# Toggle in LWC has very big active area

Tags: lightning-web-components, lws

In LWS component I have form with a toggle button and use this snippet of code for this

```
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">
               <lightning-input
                   type="toggle"
                   title={label.X}
                   checked={X}
                   label={label.C}
                   onchange={changeClosingToggle}
                   disabled={disableCurrentClosing}
                   message-toggle-active={label.Yes}
                   message-toggle-inactive={label.No}></lightning-input>
           </div>

           <template if:true={xChosen}>
               <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
                   <lightning-input
                       type="toggle"
                       title={label.X}
                       checked={closingAllToggleVal}
                       label={label.X}
                       onchange={changeClosingAllToggle}
                       message-toggle-active={label.Yes}
                       message-toggle-inactive={label.No}></lightning-input>
               </div>
           </template>
```

As result, I have a very big area where I can press and change toggle status.
[image]
But I want to press only on the toggle icon - not to whole this green area.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use lightning-layout  and layout-item with size attribute  to confine toggle area.

```
<lightning-layout >
    <lightning-layout-item size="4" padding="around-small">
          <lightning-input
               type="toggle"
               title={label.X}
               checked={X}
               label={label.C}
               onchange={changeClosingToggle}
               disabled={disableCurrentClosing}
               message-toggle-active={label.Yes}
               message-toggle-inactive={label.No}></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

layot-item official doc:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/example